# How to represent hex colors in Scala.js?

Tags: scala.js

What's the recommended way to represent hex colors in Scala.js? `org.scalajs.dom.ext.Color` can be constructed from a hex string, but I can't get the string back out later (e.g. to feed into an `<input type="color" ..>`).

Comment: Doesn't its `toString()` method returns something of the form `rgb(4, 5, 6)`?

Comment: Yes, it does. I am hesitant to rely on `toString()`, but probably I just don't understand what you are suggesting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the inability to convert the `Color` back to a hex string is an oversight. Probably best if you add a helper yourself:

```
def toHexString(c: Color): String = {
  import c._
  f"#$r%02x$g%02x$b%02x"
}

// Usage
val c = Color(255, 0, 0)
toHexString(c)  // = "#ff0000"
```

Even better of course, is if you submit this upstream so others can use it.

Comment: Thanks for the official confirmation. I will try come up with a PR.

Comment: Just FTR, I don't think I can count as official for the DOM library. The only contribution I have made to this library is releasing it a couple of times :)

Comment: Tx for the clarification :)

Comment: BTW: [My PR got merged](https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js-dom/pull/243) (still waiting for a release though)